# How to check one checkbox only for PHP

Tags: php, mysql

im doing attendance management system for my final project. Basically the old system is using paper to take the attendance. But for my system it is an online method where the lecturers have to login in order to take the attendance. Im using PHP and MySql.

So my problem is i do not know how to check one checkbox

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='P'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='A'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='PR'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='L'/></td>";
```

the letter P is for Present

the letter A is for Absence

the letter PR is for Permission

the letter L is for Late

can someone please help :)

SOLVED... Thanks everyone. I will use radio button instead of checkbox

Comment: use a radio button, not a checkbox.

Comment: `google` it, you will find so may tutorial on this!

Comment: In <form> you can't read more than one kind of object with same name. use <select><option>... or as @JonathanKuhn suggest, radio buttons instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a radio button element, not a checkbox.

**Checkbox** is for when any/all choices are acceptable.

**Radio Button** is for when only one of many choices is acceptable

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='P'/>This</br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='A'/>That</br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='PR'/>The</br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='L'/>Other</br>
</form>

<form>
    <input type='radio' name='radio' value='P'/>This</br>
    <input type='radio' name='radio' value='A'/>OR That</br>
    <input type='radio' name='radio' value='PR'/>OR The</br>
    <input type='radio' name='radio' value='L'/>OR Other</br>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is an online test of the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/A95Fq/

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a radio button, not a checkbox. Radio buttons are made to handle when you have several boxes that you want to display and have only one of those boxes checked at a time. You can use radio boxes like:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="P"> P
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="A"> A
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="PR"> PR
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="L"> L
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="P"> P
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="A"> A
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="PR"> PR
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="L"> L
```

If you notice, there are two names. Each name will be a different group.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you using radio for this purpose as you need only one option to be TRUE

```
<input type="radio" name="student1" checked="checked: value="P"> P
<input type="radio" name="student1" value="A"> A
<input type="radio" name="student1" value="PR"> PR
<input type="radio" name="student1" value="L"> L
```

After this you can check using,

```
$what_is_status=$_POST["student"];
```

$what_is_status will return P,A,PR Or L

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<input checked="checked" type='checkbox' name='checkbox' value='P'/>
```

you can change the "checked" attribute dynamically in PHP. If you want to select only one option, you should use radio instead of checkbox.